# Index is not priting and code is freezing in binary search program

Tags: c, search, binary-search

I have made a program of binary search in which I encountered a problem that the program is freezing before printing the index value of the array.
Variable `high` is for last index , `low` is for first index of the array.
I am hereby attaching the code

```
// binary search
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int binary(int a[],int n,int x);
void main()
{
    int arr[10];
    int i,x,n,r;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter number of data elements");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    printf("Enter the element to be search");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    r=binary(arr,n,x);
    if(r==-1)
    {
        printf("Not found");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Found : %d",r);
    }
    getch();
}
int binary(int a[],int n,int x)
{
    int high=n-1;
    int low=0;
    int result=-1,mid;
    while(low<=high)
    {
        mid=(high+low)/2;
        if(x==a[mid])
        {
            result=mid;
        }
        else if(x<a[mid])
        {
            high=mid-1;
        }
        else if(x>a[mid])
        {
            low=mid+1;
        }
    }
    return (result);
}
```

Comment: Have you done *any* basic debugging? Namely use a debugger and/or debug print statements to trace the execution of your program?

Comment: In `binary` you need to break out of the loop when the search item is found. It took me all of 30 seconds to find that with a debugger.

Comment: Yeah I have used while loop for that and in the end I am returning the final result

Comment: I don't think you understand. You need a `break` statement inside the `if(x==a[mid])` block.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the logic,

```
mid=(high+low)/2;
if(x==a[mid])
{
    result=mid;
}
```

if this if statement evaluates to true, then you are stuck in an infinite loop, because you do not change 'low' or 'high' the while statement always evaluates to 'true', and this if also evaluates true, as 'mid' is a function of 'high' and 'low'.

A possible fix would be to add a break statement, or raise a flag, that should be checked for.

Comment: I am not getting the problem

Comment: Correct analysis of the problem. Answer can be improved by explicitly stating how the problem can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop in your binary function is going into an infinite loop when low and high becomes equal for the case when target is present in the array. You are not breaking the loop when you get the result here

```
if(x==a[mid])
{
        result=mid;
}
```

Apply a break statement in this if statement after getting the result to exit from the loop.

P.s. You are assuming the input to be sorted here. Try not to do so.

Comment: @user6547375 please try to dry run for a small test case. you will get the problem in the code yourself.

Comment: `going into an infinite loop when low and high becomes equal` Please reconsider. The if-statement doesn't become true whenever `low == high`

Comment: ^ yes I was considering the case when the target is already present in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code a little bit:

```
mid=(high+low)/2;
    if(x==a[mid])
    {
        result=mid;
         break;       // to break the infinite loop
    }
```

Only break statement is needed in your code as above; everything else seems fine.
Hope it will help.